# How to open a file in a specific target application from a website? i.e. not the default application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

From my website I have a link to a PDF file. When the user clicks the link I want the PDF to open in Bluebeam Revu and not Adobe Acrobat.

Is it possible to suggest a target application?

Comment: You can't control user's default PDF viewer, what is set as a default application will open it

Comment: No, you've no control to set default apps in client machine - even in browser. You can use PDF viewer libraries in browser to create browser preview, but the target app which will open it depends with local user settings.